# Why potential $V=0$ for a free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, definition

Why potential $V=0$ for a free particle?

Comment: It's easier to answer if we know what exactly you don't understand. Do you know what "free particle" means? Do you know the relationship between potential and force?

Comment: @Javier I know that   Force=-grad(potential)

Answer (score 2):

A particle is free when no force is exerted on it. Since the relation between the force and the potential (energy) is
$$\vec F=-\vec\nabla V$$
then $F=0$ implies that $V={\rm Cst}$. In non-relativistic mechanics, one can shift the potential $V$ by any constant without changing the force and therefore the trajectories. It holds also with Schrödinger equation. Only the total energy is shifted by the same value. As a corollary, one can choose $V=0$.

Comment: Isn't it the electric field $\vec E$ that's the gradient of the potential? Then $\vec F=q\vec E$.

Comment: In classical mechanics, the force is related to the potential energy $V$ by $\vec F=-\vec\nabla V$. The force exerted by an electric field $E$ on a charge $q$ is indeed $\vec F=q\vec E$. It is useful to write the potential energy as $V=q\varphi$ where the electric potential $\varphi$ satisfies $\vec E=-\vec\nabla\varphi$. The problem is that very often the same notation ($V$) is used for both the potential energy and the electric potential.